# Can we inspect an object file for presence of temporaries introduced by C++ compiler?

Tags: c++, temporary, temporaries

Is there a way to inspect object file generated from code below ( file1.o ) for presence of compiler introduced temporary? What tools can we use to obtain such info from object files?

```
//file1.cpp
void func(const int& num){}
int main(){   func(2);  }
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason to do this?

Comment: I'm with @Etienne on this. Rather than asking us "How do I <neigh_impossible_task>?" ask us "How can I achieve <X>?", where X refers to the actual goal you currently (and erroneously) want to achieve by doing <neigh_impossible_task>.

Comment: Temporaries such as the `int` temporaries in `1+Foo()+2+Bar()+3` are going to be bloody hard to detect. The compiler will just use one register for the accumulation, but C++ formally had three temporaries during the evaluation.

Comment: I don't see any temporaries in the above code. Is this homework?

Comment: @Martin York, the compiler is allowed to create a temporary before binding an r-value to a reference.

Comment: @ Martin York, you got it. I hit it while solving an exercise in Stroustrup's TC++PL.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way I can think of to do this is to load up a program that uses the object file and disassemble the function in the debugger.  The program code you posted would work fine for this.  Just break on the call to `func` and then display the assembler when you single-step into the function.

In a more complex program you can usually display the assembler code for a given function by name.  Check your debugger documentation for how to do this.  On Windows (Visual Studio) you can open the `Disassembly` window and enter the name of the function to display the assembler code.

If you have the source, most compilers allow you to output assembler, sometimes mixed with the source code.  For Visual C++ this is [/Fa](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/367y26c6%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Note: If using gdb, it can open an object file directly and disassemble its functions.  `gdb file1.o`, `(gdb) disas main`, `(gdb) disas func`.  But references to other symbols will look weird.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on an ELF system and have GNU binutils you can call `readelf`, probably with the `-s` switch.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the source available, it is probably easier to look at the assembler file generated by the compiler (-save-temps for gcc). Otherwise, `objdump` is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `clang -cc1 --ast-print-xml` to get a XML representation of a translation unit. The presence of temporaries can be easily detected from the AST.